# Azure Stream Analytics Job: Property with 'username' already exists error

Tags: azure, azure-iot-hub, azure-stream-analytics

We have a StreamAnalyticsJob that we've just noticed is getting Deserialization Events 'Failed' in it's activity log from time to time.

The error posted in the JSON of the Activity Log is:

`"Property with name 'username' already exists."`

We don't have any properties named `username` in our input stream, nor does our job deserialize anything at all other than IOT Hub input.  Any clues as to what causes the failure?

Here is the redacted JSON of the error as retrieved from the Stream Analytics Job Activity Log:

```
{
"channels": "Operation",
"correlationId": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
"description": "",
"eventDataId": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
"eventName": {
    "value": "streamingNode0.iot-hub-by-consumer-group_6_00000000_0000_0000_0000_000000000000#9$0",
    "localizedValue": "streamingNode0.iot-hub-by-consumer-group_6_00000000_0000_0000_0000_000000000000#9$0"
},
"category": {
    "value": "Administrative",
    "localizedValue": "Administrative"
},
"eventTimestamp": "2018-02-14T23:08:25.1981067Z",
"id": "/subscriptions/00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000/resourceGroups/red-test-rg/providers/Microsoft.StreamAnalytics/streamingjobs/IOT-Entry-Point/events/00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000/ticks/636542465051981067",
"level": "Informational",
"operationId": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
"operationName": {
    "value": "Deserialize Events",
    "localizedValue": "Deserialize Events"
},
"resourceGroupName": "red-test-rg",
"resourceProviderName": {
    "value": "Microsoft.StreamAnalytics",
    "localizedValue": "Microsoft.StreamAnalytics"
},
"resourceType": {
    "value": "Microsoft.StreamAnalytics/streamingjobs",
    "localizedValue": "Microsoft.StreamAnalytics/streamingjobs"
},
"resourceId": "/subscriptions/00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000/resourceGroups/red-test-rg/providers/Microsoft.StreamAnalytics/streamingjobs/IOT-Entry-Point",
"status": {
    "value": "Failed",
    "localizedValue": "Failed"
},
"subStatus": {
    "value": "",
    "localizedValue": ""
},
"submissionTimestamp": "2018-02-14T23:09:01.480545Z",
"subscriptionId": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
"properties": {
    "Message Time": "2018-02-14 23:08:25Z",
    "Error": "",
    "Message": "Property with name 'username' already exists.",
    "Type": "SerializerError",
    "Correlation ID": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"
},
"relatedEvents": []
```

}

Is there a clue in the above JSON as to the exact input message that cause the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Deserialization errors should include the message partition ID and offset, you may want to retrieve the original message and check if the payload is valid JSON.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/stream-analytics/stream-analytics-malformed-events

Comment: Unfortunately the error JSON has no partition Id or Offset data.  I will post a redacted (no account identifying info) copy of the JSON I do get.

Answer (score 0):

In your activity log, select Diagnostic Error instead of Deserialize Events as highlighted in the [snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Ty2q.png). Then you should see something like:

```
"properties": {
        "Message Time": "2018-03-20 21:13:12Z",
        "Error": null,
        "Message": "First Occurred: 03/20/2018 21:13:10 | Resource Name: ehIncorrectJson | Message: Could not deserialize the input event(s) from   resource 'Partition: [0], Offset: [3936], SequenceNumber: [69]' as Json. Some possible reasons: 1) Malformed events 2) Input source configured with incorrect serialization format",
        "Type": "DiagnosticMessage",
        "Correlation ID": "42d778ec-bd2c-42a0-87be-212245d2c28b"
    },
```

You can then use the information in the message field to debug as Min he pointed out.